# Why are there two Utilities folders in my Applications folder?

Tags: macos, utilities

MacOs Ventura 13.6.1, I don't recall seeing two Utilities folders before. In fact I thought it was impossible to have identically-named files (or folders) in the same location (Applications in this case).

What's going on?
[image]

Comment: That's very unusual. I would verify that the filenames and paths are in fact the same, using Get Info (or better, Terminal). I would then verify the disk volume with Disk Utility's First Aid.

Comment: Do they both contain the same files?

Answer (score 0):

After a reboot it is back to normal (just one Utilities folder).  It was actually a non-scheduled reboot, our power went out briefly during a thunderstorm yesterday.  So I can't perform further research, but am glad things appear normal.  I suppose I should still check the disk.